# submitted forms with the same name to a php script?

Tags: php, javascript

Is it possible to submit forms with input checkboxes, each containing the same name, to a PHP script?

Is it possible to loop through the names to get all the values?

I am building a message system, and users can add/remove recipients dynamically. When they do, a hidden checkbox is generated in the form containing the value, yet I'm not sure what to do with the name. On the php end, on top of the recipients a subject and a message are submitted, and the script needs to loop through each name and perform various SQL tasks. I know there are much better ways of doing this, and feel free to suggest, but I'd really like to know if it can get done this way. Comment if you need to see code, but I warn you, it's really confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="samename[]">
// on the post/get:
foreach( $_POST['samename'] as $eachId ){
  // do whatever you want.  build the where in a query, ' set = '.$eachId
}
```

Comment: ah i knew there had to be something for this, makes so much sense, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, use the same name with `[]` after it, it will cause all of the values to be stored in an array on PHP.

```
<input type=checkbox value=1 name=check[]>
<input type=checkbox value=2 name=check[]>
<input type=checkbox value=3 name=check[]>
<input type=checkbox value=4 name=check[]>
<input type=checkbox value=5 name=check[]>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, array of post, look at this example:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
<form action="form.php" method="POST">
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle[]" value="Bike" /> I have a bike<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle[]" value="Car" /> I have a car 
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Notice how `vehicle` has the square brackets?